# Cannot upload the GeoJSON file in new iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload a Routing App Coverage File in the **NEW** iTunes Connect.
The file name is example.geojson. I get the following error:

```
Invalid file extension: Your routing app coverage file must use the .geojson extension
```

I tried in Chrome and Safari even changed the name to example.GeoJSON.

I validated the contents of the file in http://geojsonlint.com/

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi.. You fixed this issue?

Comment: No contacted Apple support, waiting for response

Comment: Okay Thank you.You know how to remove Prerelease builds in new itunes connect?

Comment: No, they are permanent, once uploaded they cannot be deleted. You can increase your build number to upload another one

Comment: Okay thank you very much. Now I see message "Submit your builds using Xcode 6 or later, or Application Loader 2.9.1 or later." But I have Xcode 5.1.1 Apple will approve this build?

Comment: Not at the mac at this moment, look around in stackoverflow, or ask this question

Answer (score 7):

When uploading a .geojson I found that you newlines may cause it to not be saved on iTunes Connect but still be validated on geojsonlint.

For example:

**FAILS:**

```
{ "type": "MultiPolygon", 
  "coordinates": [ 
    [[[14.094369,36.060248],
    [14.138314, 35.869068],
    [14.428181,35.746154],
    [14.744622,35.782218],
    [14.648492,36.028047],
    [14.181083, 36.192884],
    [14.094369,36.060248]
    ]]]
}
```

**SUCCEEDS:**

```
{ "type": "MultiPolygon", 
  "coordinates": [ 
    [[[14.094369,36.060248], [14.138314, 35.869068], [14.428181,35.746154], [14.744622,35.782218], [14.648492,36.028047], [14.181083, 36.192884], [14.094369,36.060248]]]
    ]
}
```

Comment: This worked for me too. Ugh, such a pain that this isn't more obvious. Thanks man.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I solved this by taking the default geojson file provided by Apple at:
[Providing directions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html)
(Listing 7-2)

and then i took the coordinates from github project:

[Countries](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries)

It worked by saving the file as `example.GeoJSON`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error message about .geojson extension. I opened it in BBEdit, delete leading spaces and tab and reformat it with JSBeautifier. After that I can upload it to iTunes Connect. The problem was not related to .geojson extension but to the content of the file (probably a mix of space and tab)

Answer (score 0):

Last night I got the same error persistently. This morning, however, the same file uploaded without issues.

I'm hoping this has nothing to do with it, but I finally renamed the file so that the letter casing was the same as the name of the standard (.GeoJSON). The file wasn't fit yesterday despite all the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but there is an easy solution.
Use Xcode an make your file. You can add an geojson to your project, insert your data. After all load this file to iTunes.

[image]

If your content is valid (check it here: [geojsonlint](http://geojsonlint.com/)), you get it to iTunes.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

I was having and the same issue but when I export screenshot without alpha, issue solved and upload to Itunes.